# .Net Core 3.1 IActionFilter get required param in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As the title says i am trying to fetch the required param in my route:

`https://localhost:44386/api/Users/c6b44b17-1b05-4ab6-a8c0-6968b4ea1ced`

This is my Filter which i put a breakpoint to see what is the value of each.

Unfortunately the first two doesn't have anything even if i specify the key (e.g. `Query["_id"]`).

The third one fetches the array of route which is correct but i don't want to use the last index value as it feels to be just a hack.

I've seen the docs and i can't find a simpler way below without touching the endpoint routing config and explicitly defining this specific route (since i might end up with tons of routes which might require this same scenario).

Any help will be truly appreciated.

```
public class ProfileIsCreatorFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var query = context.HttpContext.Request.Query;
            var queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            var route = context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues;
        }
}
```

```
[HttpGet("{_id}"), Authorize, ProfileIsCreatorFilter]
public ActionResult<User> GetUser(Guid _id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I have simplified everything to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access all route specific values in the filter-context. The context contains a [`RouteData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routedata?view=aspnetcore-3.1) dictionary:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    string myvalue = context.RouteData.Values["mykey"];
}
```

You can find more infos to ActionFilters in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#action-filters).

Comment: I'm so silly, i didn't notice this. I saw it was a Dictionary but i dont know why i didin't bother to test out the keys. Thanks a lot, you the man!